# Spotting mistake: unnecessary given condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, economics, fake-proofs

I have solved the following problem without using a given premise. Could someone please spot whether I have done something wrong?

> Suppose we have a relation $\geq$ that is transitive, but not
>   necessarily complete. For nonempty $A$, we define 
>   $$ C(A)=\{x\in A: x\geq y\text{ for all }y\in A\},\\ 
> D(A)=\{x\in A: \text{there exists no }y\in A\text{ such that }y>x\}. 
> $$ 
>   Prove that $C(A)\subset D(A)$. Prove that $\geq$ is
>   complete iff $D(A)$ is nonempty for all finite $A$.

**Proof**. For the first claim, suppose $x\in C(A)$. If $\exists y\in A$ such that $y>x$ then, in particular, $\neg(x\geq y)$, contradicting $x\in C(A)$. This means $x\in D(A)$.

The second claim is where I might have made a mistake: I claim that $D(A)$ is always nonempty as long as $A$ is finite; that is, completeness is irrelevant. Suppose otherwise that $D(A)$ is empty and consider $x_1\in A$. Then, there exists $x_2\in A$ such that $x_2>x_1$.  In turn, there must be $x_3\in A$ such that $x_3>x_2$. In this manner, we can build a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in which $x_{n+1}>x_n$ and transitivity implies that the elements of the sequence are distinct. But this violates the finiteness of $A$, giving us our contradiction. ∎

---

**Appendix**. Some definitions for those unfamiliar with this context:

- Transitivity: $x\geq y$ and $y\geq z$ imply $x\geq z$.
- Completeness: $\forall x,y$, either $x\geq y$ or $y\geq x$ (or both).
- $x>y$: $x\geq y$ and $\neg(y\geq x)$.

Comment: How is this even remotely related to economics? I don't like this tag.

Comment: Preference relations are foundations of microeconomics. People use them to build utility functions.

Comment: Yes, but the question itself has nothing to do with it. It's like putting a physics tag on an elliptic curve question, yes there are applications of elliptic curves in physics, but the question is about elliptic curves.

Comment: I think the correct statement would be : prove that $\le$ is complete if and only if $D(A) \subsetneq A$.

Comment: I see your point about the tag, but I got the question from an economics context and I think people who like economics might be interested in this question. It's a minor issue anyway. I won't comment further on the tag. If you feel that strongly about it, feel free to edit. I won't object.

Comment: It's okay, if you see a point, keep it there, but my question was legitimate. Anyway. I think if you take a trivial partial order $(X,\le)$ (i.e. the only $y$ related to $x$ is $x$ itself), then you have an example of a non-complete partial order with $D(A) = A \neq \varnothing$ for all $A$, so the statement is definitely wrong.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva This is pretty fundamentally different from your example. Preference relations are the first topic covered in a first course in graduate microeconomics using the standard textbook (MWG). I've never heard of any physics program that starts with elliptic curves.

Comment: @bof: I copied the question correctly but you are right in that $C(A)$ would make the claim correct. I'm pretty satisfied with the comments so far so if you (or someone else) wants to type up a short answer, I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: Say, how are things in North Korea? Hope you're feeling better.

Comment: Haha, well enough for me to sit here to do math. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian : Note that I'm not --supposed-- to assume this has anything to do with economics... there is nowhere mentioned "economics" in the question (except in the tag), so I just assume this is a question on partial orders... from my point of view it was super confusing to see this. Anyway, it's okay, I'm cool with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is impeccable. Looks like a typo in the problem. The last line should read: Prove that $\ge$ is complete iff $C(A)$ is nonempty for all (nonempty) finite $A$.